# Azure Data Factory: Excel -> Csv. How to handle line breaks in column headers?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

So I converted my Excel-file to CSV by using the Copy activity in Azure Data factory. The problem is that the column headers in the excel file has line breaks, which causes the csv file to look funny

The data in the excel-file looks like this

```
col1 name col2  col3 name
          name 

data1     data2      data3
```

which causes the csv file to look like this after the copy activity.

```
col1 name,col2
name, col3 name,
"data1", "data2", "data3"
```

Some people mentioned that I could use Data Flows to remove the \n from the column headers before I write it to csv. But since I am not using data flows anywhere else I would like to refrain from doing that.

When the file has been written to csv I will read it with Databricks. However, I have trouble ingesting the file when the column headers are on multiple rows in the CSV file.

What is the optimal solution to fix this?

Comment: See if your `name,` , `col3 name,` are in separate cells at 2nd row in your excel file.

Comment: provide the screenshot of your excel file data

Answer (score 0):

First, I tried the code below:

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("multiline", "true").csv("abfss://folder02@dilipstg.dfs.core.windows.net/linebreak.csv")
new_column_names = [name.replace("\n", "") for name in df.columns]
df = df.toDF(*new_column_names)
```

**Results:**

[image]

Then, I tried the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("multiline", "true").csv("abfss://folder02@dilipstg.dfs.core.windows.net/linebreak.csv")
new_column_names = [name.replace("\n", "") for name in df.columns]
df = df.withColumn('name\r', regexp_replace(df['name\r'], '\r', ''))
df = df.toDF(*new_column_names)
df = df.withColumnRenamed('name\r', 'name')
df.show()
```

**Results:**

```
+-----+----+---------+----+-----+
| col1|name|col2name |Col3| name|
+-----+----+---------+----+-----+
|data1|NULL|    data2|NULL|data3|
+-----+----+---------+----+-----+
```

In the above code, I read the CSV file into a DataFrame using `spark.read.csv`. I set the header option to `true` to indicate that the first row contains column headers, and the multiline option to `true` to allow reading multiline records.

Next, I created a list of new column names by removing any newline characters **(\n)** from the existing column names. I used `regexp_replace` to remove any carriage return characters **(\r)** from the 'name\r' column.

Then, I renamed the DataFrame columns to the new column names without line breaks. Finally, I used `.withColumnRenamed` to rename the 'name\r' column to '**name**'.